# How to reduce thickness of object

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, edit-mode

i have just finished modelling a Newton's Cradle, but I noticed the bars are too thick, I did not use a solidify modifier. I have tried scaling it in the x and y axis but is just makes it look flat. I wanna reduce the thickness, how would I do that?

[image]

I know the question seems a bit vague, but it is way too thick and i really don't wanna have to re-model them. Is their a way?

Comment: Which question about the same thing is it? Check here: http://bfy.tw/Fxht and check every possible link to learn how to make it properly. Also this: http://bfy.tw/Fxi1

Comment: @LukeD https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15650

Comment: ? i just wanna know how to reduce thickness. this has nothing to do about pipes and tubes.

Comment: @Aoradon and what's your point here? Did you read answers and comments there, or did you just pasted it because it has LMGTFY in title? Optimus this has everything to do with tubes and pipes. Once you know how to make them properly you wouldn't need to ask series questions about them which are either easily discoverable on the internet or just duplicates from BSE.

Answer (score 2):

A possible modifier based solution is to use displace with a black texture. Then the strength parameter can to be used to control the shrinkage amount. This approach does't change the total length of the bar/curve. Depending on how your bars are modeled YMMV.

Without displace:
[image]
With displace:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go into edit mode select both of your bars (You can use L key to do that quickly) the just hold alt key and press s to scale them and if everything goes right you must get what you need.